# How can I run a JavaScript AJAX request from a PHP function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Currently the success of my PHP `if statement` just reloads the page:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Added: link to the site here http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/index.php

However I want to run a JavaScript basic AJAX request instead to load a page `register-success.php` into the div:

```
function loadSuccess()
{var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else
  {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {document.getElementById("login-register-wrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}
xmlhttp.open("GET","register-success.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

However I am unsure about this combination of JavaScript and PHP and how to implement it

1) Is there some sort of PHP function I can wrap around a piece of JS to make it enact it?

2) Is there a way to do a simple AJAX call like this in PHP instead? Or something that mimics it?

Here is the function that validates my form. If the form validates, I need to reload with AJAX and call in `register-success` file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['sign-up'])){
        // username
        if (isset($_POST['username'])){
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;

            if(strlen($username) > 3){
                    if(strlen($username) < 31){
                        if(user_exists($username) === true){
                            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'That username is already taken. Sorry, please try again with a different username.';
                        } else{
                            // passed
                            // continue
                        }
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is greater than 30 characters.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is less than 3 characters.';
                }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is not entered.';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['password'])){
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

            if(strlen($password) >= 8){
                    $password = hash_function($password);
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Your secret password is too short. You should make a password with at least 8 letters.";
                }

        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You haven't put in a password.";
        }

        // Email address
        if (!empty($_POST['email_address'])){
            $email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email_address']));
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'] = $email_address;
            if(strlen($email_address) > 10){ // email address less than 10
                    if(strlen($email_address) < 161){ // if longer than 160

                        if(email_valid($email_address) == false){ // email address invalid format
                                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address has been put in wrong. Please check and try again.";
                            }
                            else{
                                // passed min length, passed max length, passed validation
                                // Continue
                            }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The email address is too long.';
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address is too short. It can't be shorter than 10 letters.";
                }
        }
        else{// passed (no email input)
        }

        if (isset($_POST['tos'])){
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['tos'] = $_POST['tos'];
            if(empty($_SESSION['status']['register']['error'])){
                if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

                    // Success!!
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['success'] = true;

                    // Sends an email

                    send_email($email_address);

                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    die();
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Something went wrong. We're sorry. Please try again.";
                }
            } else {}
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You have to agree to the House Rules to be able to sign up.";
        }

        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        // success script with AJAX goes here
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: do you want to add this "register-success.php" server- or clientside?

Comment: It doesn't matter. In fact it doesn't have to be PHP. It will just be a simple page saying that you've successfully created an account. But it needs to be loaded through AJAX into `login-register-wrapper`

Comment: @Francesca I think you are getting the logic wrong in using an ajax call to include the response from your php scripts. You better don't use those headers to redirect between the pages.

Comment: the javascript code you posted is fine you would only have to send the parameters for your registration as well

Comment: @joz I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think I don't understand your question yet... If I got it right all you need to achieve want you want is (almost) already in your question.

http://pastebin.com/veVseMgp

This should be the basic logic of the file that you then load into your website using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write javascript code outside PHP Block, so after ?>. Ajax call are made from client side, so only with javascript.

To simplify your code, you can use a javascript lib, like jQuery, so the code is more simple:

```
$('#login-register-wrapper').load('register-success.php');
```

You can made this with PHP like Kamehameha Answer, using ob_get_contents().

In this case, without parameters from html page, the result is the same, the content from processed.

**Edit:**

Based in comments, you need to redirect to 'index.php' with some parameter, like:

```
header('Location: index.php?success=1');
```

So, in index.php, you can write some like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 1) {
    echo '<script>function loadSuccess()
{var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else
  {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {document.getElementById("login-register-wrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}
xmlhttp.open("GET","register-success.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();}</script>';
}
```

**Edit:**

In tag body, you need to call javascript function loadSuccess(). Like this:

```
<body onload="loadSuccess()">
```

Comment: But how can I write it outside of the PHP function when it needs to run on the success of the PHP function?

Comment: But your PHP success function is in register-success.php or other page?

Comment: No, it's on the register-form page. I'll add it to the OP. When the register function completes, it should reload with AJAX. So I need to get the AJAX call to work within the PHP.

Comment: login-register-wrapper ir in register-success.php? If yes, maybe you not need to make a ajax call, only load a message in this wrapper

Comment: No it is not in register-success.php. It is in index.php, which is the first page you see. Then, when you click "make new account" it runs an AJAX call which loads register-form.php into the main div. Once you've completed the form, and it's passed through a PHP function, the success of it needs to call another AJAX script that reloads register-success.php into the main div.

Comment: You can see the site here: http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/index.php - the PHP register code shown in the OP runs when you hit the "make my account" button. But the success doesn't work, because I need to run it through AJAX. I can easily make it redirect to another page for your "success" message but I don't want it to load a new page, I want it to reload back into the main div. No page refresh.

Comment: So this form is send to register-success.php in a normal request (not Ajax). If is ok and user account was created, register-success.php returns for index.php, and is in this point than you need make a ajax request to show message in login-register-wrapper?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You can see in the PHP code above I have placed a comment where I need the code to run. "// success script with AJAX goes here" - where you see that, is where I need to do an AJAX call to load register-success.php into `login-register-wrapper`. Hence my query about running AJAX within PHP.

Comment: I understand now, when you click "I want to make a new account" the page make a ajax call to get register-form.php. So, after make a new account you need put a message in this form?

Comment: Yep that's it. It's like a chain of AJAX calls. There is the main page, then there is register-form (where you register) and register-success. You need to go to register-success after you've gone to register-form. But they all load into the same div using AJAX.

Comment: The problem is than in register-success.php not have the element login-register-wrapper, so you need redirect with header() to index.php again with some parameter like index.php?success=1 and if index.php have this parameter you can ajax call in index.php.

Comment: Why does it need to? the wrapper is in the index page. So can't an AJAX call just output this into the page?

Comment: You can echo a javascript with ajax call inside php with echo, like my example with jQuery: 'echo <script>$("#login-register-wrapper').load('register-success.php');'. But this try get a HTML element with id 'login-register-wrapper', if this not exists in this page, nothing happens.

Comment: @gabrieloliveira I would put this logic into the register.php, not the index. If registering fails, register.php responds with an error, if not, response will be "success".

Comment: @gabrieloliveira The php code you supplied appears to be invalid :(

Comment: No error but it doesn't work. For a start, putting it in the index page won't work. It needs to go in the register function I have posted above? That doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to put header('Location: index.php?success=1'); replace header('Location: index.php'); in register-success.php where you redirect to index.php, not above // // success script with AJAX goes here. Above this, you put a message like echo 'Your account was created';

Comment: I edit answer to complete javascript code in index.php

Comment: I don't have Location: index.php in register-success. Register success page is just text and that is all it should be.

Comment: In posted register-success.php code, has a header('Location:index.php'); in final of code.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply have to create a extra .php file that only has the register-logic in it. Assuming you have a form with all the data in it, you would then use javascript to make a submit button and send all the data (for example via get or post) to this .php file on your server using a ajax request. answer would only be the html you want to include in your wrapper. This response from the server would then simply be displayed by modifying the dom of your current site

Comment: I can't see this working properly, because my register function has some validation in it. Is not possible to do this without making a new function? Can you not do AJAX requests at all? Seems odd.

Comment: What do you mean by validation? This php-file can to the exact same validation as you would want to do it in index.php As php is only server-side you cannot alter a page after it has been sent to the client.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. All I need is to work out how to run the Javascript above inside the if statement in this file.

Comment: so your aim is not to load the success asynchron, but you only want to  include the register_succes_file into the other webpage?

Comment: No, the success page should load through ajax, just the same as the register page before it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple !
do the following :

- Add this line to your php code so it can run on the success of your PHP Function :

> echo "
>       document.getElementById('success').click();
>       ";

- Now add this HTML line into your page , so it can load the

> ```
> <a id="success" style="visibility:hidden;">Success</a>
> <script>
> var el = document.getElementById('success');
> el.onclick = loadSuccess();
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Can't get this working. Just takes you to the index page again.

Comment: Where? I've posted it above. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Why did you add    : 
header('Location: index.php');